# SQL Server 2008 - Pivot Table ISNULL = 0 Not working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am working on joining two tables and display the result in pivot table.  This is my first time doing the pivot, so I am still very new to this.

I have this query below is display the result almost I what I want, but one small thing I couldn't figure out. if the value isNull, then convert it to 0. like I normally do this isNull(value, 0).

```
SELECT * FROM 
( 
SELECT oa.OpptID, o.OpptName, ISNULL(Amount, 0) AS Amount, BucketNameID
FROM dbo.Opportunity o 
LEFT JOIN dbo.ProductBucketAmount oa ON oa.OpptID = o.OpptID
WHERE oa.OpptID IN (123, 456) 
) p
PIVOT
(
    Sum(p.Amount)
    FOR p.BucketNameID
    IN (
        [1], [2], [3], [4], [5]
    )   
) AS pvt
```

If I do like this for the PIVOT columns, it will works, but looks so messy codes. Plus, I want to SELECT all columns everytime (SELECT * FROM...)

```
SELECT OpptName, OpptName, ISNULL([1], 0) AS '1', ISNULL([2], 0) AS '2'  ... etc ...
```

Please help or suggestion

Thanks,

Comment: Yes this is possible. You can find plenty pivot examples on so. One of my questions contains an example as well. If you try to solve your question and are stuck at a certain point with a specific question you will get additional help.

Comment: I tried to solve and stuck. I updated my post with where I am stuck Anyone? please help! Thanks.

Comment: I tried ""isnull(Sum(p.Amount), 0)"" in the PIVOT statement and getting an error : is not a recognized aggregate function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you have to do it outside of the pivot, so yes, it's somewhat messy. The reason is that some of those `NULL`s are being constructed *by* the pivot from no input rows - so there's no earlier stage at which you can convert the `NULL`s to `0`s.

And, as you've also discovered, the `PIVOT` clause itself isn't flexible. It has to have exactly an aggregate function specified, not an arbitrary expression containing the aggregate.

So what you have:

```
SELECT OpptName, OpptName, ISNULL([1], 0) AS '1', ISNULL([2], 0) AS '2'  ... etc
```

is about the best that you can do. (And there's no way to do this as some form of `SELECT * ...` - you have to convert each column separately)